# Linked server connection issue with SQL Server and Lotus Notes

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to established connection between SQL Server and Lotus notes database (.nsf) file using Linked Server.

But, while creating linked server connection i m facing some issue. Please check the image for same issue.

Any idea how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Does the ODBC source 'notes' work, can you open it and click test. Is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Spörri ODBC is 64 bit, and i have installed 64 bit SQL as well. But when i m running SSMS, i don't know why in Task Manager it shows as 32 bit SQL running.

Comment: Now it becomes a question of versions - the error you are getting is here. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592607